# How far was the EXPLICIT abc-conjecture verified?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, conjectures

I came across the EXPLICIT abc-conjecture which states the following :

Let $a,b,c\ge 1$ be coprime integers with $a+b=c$ (The condition $a+b=c$ implies that "pairwise coprime" and "coprime" are equivalent conditions).

Denote $n=rad(abc)$ , where $rad(m)$ is the product of the distinct prime factors of $m$ and $\omega=\omega(n)$ the number of distinct prime factors of $n$.

Then, the inequality $$c<\frac{6}{5}\cdot n \cdot\frac{\ln(n)^{\omega}}{\omega!} $$

holds

Questions :

> - I verified the conjecture for $a,b\le 10^4$ and noticed that it is false for the pair $(a,b)=(1,1)$. I assume this pair is ruled out and $a<b$ is assumed WLOG. Is this correct ?
> - Upto which $c$ has this conjecture be verified ?

Comment: Baker's Explicit abc-Conjecture and Waring's problem

Comment: This paper shows that the waring-problem can be completely solved assuming the explicit abc-conjecture. I do not think that the pair $(1/1)$ plays any role in the proof. Am I correct ?

Comment: I assume $ \ln (n)^{\omega}$ means  $(\ln n)^{\omega}$  because if it meant $\ln (n^{\omega})$ it would probably have appeared as $\omega \ln n.$

Comment: It is definitely a good idea to assume $a\ne b,$ for if $p$ is an odd prime and $a=b=p$ then  the inequality says $2p^3< (6/5)p(\ln 2p)^2 ,$ which is false.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet The abc-conjecture (also the explicit abc-conjecture) assums that $a$ and $b$ are coprime which is not the case if $a=b$ and $a>1$. I only found one counterexample , namely  $(a/b)=(1/1)$ and I just wonder if the author(s) has(have) forgotten to mention $(a/b) \ne (1/1)$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes, it should be $(\ln(n))^\omega$, which some authors would write as $\ln^{\omega} (n)$